# How do I replace Windows 7 Ultimate with Kubuntu without loosing my files in partition D wich is NTFS?

Tags: system-installation, windows, windows-7, kubuntu, ntfs

I want to replace my Windows 7 Ultimate with Kubuntu. I have a big D partition that is hard to backup and I want to install kubuntu without loosing the partition and still be accesible in kubuntu. The partition is NTFS.

Comment: It's just a matter of leaving that partition untouched. Anyway, I would not do anything as near as dangerous as a operating system wipe and installation without a good backup. No, let me say again that --- what are you doing without a backup? My laptop HD died one month ago, completely, all by its own...

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `wich` to `which`, `loosing` to `losing`, and `accesible` to `accessible`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do not delete your "D" partition you won't lose the DATA on it. Try creating different partitions where you can install Kubuntu. You will need 2 partitions to install kubuntu. 1 for swap and 1 for system file. At the end you should have at least 3 partition (2 for Kubuntu and 1 for your "D") if you haven't deleted your windows partition.

If you can open the partition tool in windows or in linux and take a screenshot/picture it would really help. I would be able to tell you which partiton you can and cannot delete. Linux can access ntfs just fine so you won't need to change anything on your "D" in order to access it from Kubuntu.

itSp4x

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 in drive D:. Drive C:  contains Windows 8.1 . My Laptop has 4GB ram so i didn't even create partition for swap. I am running Ubuntu now and ram consumption is 1.2 GB. Most of the time it takes only 800 MB. So no need for swap memory.

Thus my point is if your ram is 4GB or more , you can install Kubuntu in drive C: without creating swap partition and without any loss of data from other partitions.